# phyloseq stepwise forward selection

Tags: r, environment-variables, rda, phyloseq

i am working with multivariate data, trying to relate soil bacterial diversity (obtained by metabarcoding) to environmental factors to see which factors explain the most variation of the bacterial diversity. I am using the phyloseq package to do most of the analysis. I managed to code different types of ordination by e.g.

```
ps.rda <- ordinate(ps, formula = ps ~ ., method = "RDA")
```

However I would like to do a RDA with a stepwise forward selection of significant environmental variables. (like the `ordistep()` function in the `vegan` package). 
Do you know a way to code this in the phyloseq package?
Any advice is greatly appreciated.